# Calculating betweenness centrality using two or more edge weights?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, igraphm

I recently became interested in complexity science through a project I'm working on, so I wondered whether one could calculate the Betweenness Centrality using two or more edge weights concurrently.

I have limited knowledge on network theory but I'm keen on learning more about it.

Specifically, let us [import](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/crailtap/street-network-of-new-york-in-graphml?select=manhatten.graphml) the graph corresponding to the Manhattan streets from Kaggle (link up top):

```
g = Import["manhatten.graphml", "GraphML"]
```

If I understand graphs correctly this is a directed connected graph.

Using the [IGraphM](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html) package:

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
```

one can calculate the Betweenness Centrality of the graph:

```
(IGBetweenness@g)[[1 ;; 4]]
```

Output: `{308328., 79947.4, 328558., 61435.4}`

Then let us assign weights to the graph:

```
weightedGraph1 = 
 Graph[VertexList[g], EdgeList[g], 
  EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{5, 55}, EdgeCount[g]]];
```

Let's assume these random numbers correspond to the minutes needed to traverse a street in the Manhattan streets network.

Now let us create another weighted graph using the length of the streets as a weight:

```
weightedGraph2 =
  SetProperty[g,
   EdgeWeight -> (AnnotationValue[{g, EdgeList[g]}, "length"] // 
      ToExpression)];
```

We can calculate centralities of weighted networks with IGraphM (my understanding is that the build in Mathematica function cannot be used for weighted graphs):

```
(IGBetweenness@weightedGraph1)[[1 ;; 4]]
```

Output: `{373256., 61121., 336140., 74528.}`

and

```
(IGBetweenness@weightedGraph2)[[1 ;; 4]]
```

Output: `{562250., 153397., 220102., 765234.}`

So far so good. The question is. Can we somehow use both weights concurrently and calculate a betweenness centrality for both weights?

What I thought of is dividing the edge weight corresponding to length with the edge weight corresponding to time:

```
(AnnotationValue[{g, EdgeList[g]}, "length"] // ToExpression)/
 RandomReal[{5, 55}, EdgeCount[g]]
```

and assign this to `g` to calculate a "speed" betweenness centrality and this actually works. But this uses one weight again. Can we do something like this

```
EdgeWeight -> {weight1, weight2}
```

instead?

Comment: You ask us _"But is this the way to go?"_, but you don't tell us where you want to go :) Certainly you can do it this way, but whether "this is the way to go" depends on what you actually want to calculate and which property of the graph you are interested in.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! I'm still exploring graphs and their properties. I want to see how far I can get by calculating their properties. I think I have an understanding of what centrality means with one weight used or without weights. But I wondered whether two weights can be used concurrently. Let me modify my question. Thanks :)

Comment: Mathematica has a built-in function for computing centralities of weighted directed graphs. I tested it.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, I tried `(BetweennessCentrality@weightedGraph2)[[1 ;; 4]]` and it returns `{308386., 79974.4, 328718., 61437.5}` which is the same result we get for `(BetweennessCentrality@g)[[1 ;; 4]]`, i.e., the build-in function ignores weights. Are you aware of another function?

Comment: @TugrulTemel What do you mean by "centralities" specifically? OP was asking about _betweenness_. Mathematica's `BetweennessCentrality` does not take weights into account. Let's not conflate different kinds of centralities.

Comment: @cconsta1: I think there are various ways to formulate your question. You might want to clarify your objective more because there are different centrality measures which have different meanings depending on the context. For example, `EigenvectorCentrality`. It measures which type of vertices to which a given vertex is connected. In your case, you might make simple computation with `w=distance/time` before you build the graph. This way you can use a single weight `w` for each edge and compute the centrality of the new weighted graph with `w`.

Comment: @cconsta1 This is not really a Mathematica question. You seem to be asking whether it makes sense to use a ratio of travel time and travel distance as the definition of your edge lengths. It is up to you to decide whether this makes sense for your application. If you ask me, I don't see how this makes sense. Lengths should be additive, while the quantity you compute is not. But in the end this is neither a programming problem, nor a mathematical problem, and there is no objective answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks for the comment. I was asking whether both weights can be taken into account at the same time when calculating Betweenness Centrality. Dividing them is something I came up with but I was asking whether something like this `EdgeWeight -> {weight1, weight2}` can be assigned to a graph when calculating centralities. Shall I modify the question?

Comment: @Szabolcs: I was confused with `EdgeBetweennessCentrality` (EBC), in which case both `IGraphM` and `Mathematica` produce the same result using a weighted matrix (?). Anyway, as you said, OP is asking a question on `BetwennessCentrality`, not `EBC`.

Comment: Betweenness centrality uses a single edge weight, more precisely edge _length_. It sounds like you are looking to calculate something else than betweenness. We can talk about that but firsts you'd need to give a mathematically precise description of the concept you are trying to compute. However, saying this is not really helpful advice, I guess. The real question is your motivation for wanting to take both into account, and what you are trying to quantify in the end. That is a research question though that makes for an open-ended discussion and is not really a good fit here ...

Comment: @TugrulTemel Yes, weirdly, `EdgeBetweennessCentrality` supports weights, while `BetweennessCentrality` does not. It's been like that since these functions were added to Mathematica. Be careful though that `EdgeBetweennessCentrality` returns _twice_ the correct result for undirected graphs (or we can say that it uses an unusual definition that is not used by anyone else ...)

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you for the last comment. It makes sense that edges can only have one weight and that weight corresponds to length. In this case, my naive approach of dividing the length of a street with the time needed to traverse it makes no meaningful sense. Yes, I'm working on a research project exploring concepts such as centrality, time for traversing, etc for a transportation network. However, for the strictly Mathematica part of my question, this expression `EdgeWeight -> {weight1, weight2}` doesn't work. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Szabolc: Thanks for the comment. Do you know what definition MMA uses in the computation of `EBC`?. This is a warning for me because I have used it in several papers. In may computations, I also used `IGraphM` and MMA to check if both produce the same result. They do produce the same result!

Comment: `EdgeBetweennessCentrality[Graph[{1 <-> 2}]]` returns 2. I believe it considers 1 -> 2 and 2 -> 1 as two distinct shortest paths. This is not customary, and not consistent with how `BetweennessCentrality[Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}]]` (correctly) returns 1 for the middle vertex. For _undirected_ graphs, `EdgeBetweennessCentrality` will always returns twice the value than in the conventional definition.